# VUE Error: Cannot find module 'lru-cache'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Good morning, first I would like to apologize for my English.

I am having a problem when creating a project to follow, I am taking the following steps.

**STEP 1:** npm install @vue/cli

**STEP 2:** vue create myproject

In the second step, I have the following error.

```
PS C:\Users\Bruno\Desktop\vue\VUE-CLI> vue create myproject
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'lru-cache'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\lib\env.js
- C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\index.js
- C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\lib\env.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Bruno\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli-shared-utils\\lib\\env.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Bruno\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli-shared-utils\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Bruno\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\bin\\vue.js'
  ]
}
PS C:\Users\Bruno\Desktop\vue\VUE-CLI>
```

Comment: First of all, `npm install @vue/cli` will install the module in the local directory, however in your call stack, it looks like you are using a global installation of vue cli. The problem seems to be within the global installation of vue/cli, so you could try to uninstall it with `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli` (deleting node_modules in C:\\Users\\Bruno\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules would also do the trick) and re-install it globally, after `npm cache clean` with `npm install -g @vue/cli`. If you want to use the local installation, you need to refer to the binary in node_modules/.bin/vue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using npx maybe? Ensuring you have the latest updates

`npx @vue/cli create my-project`

Is the folder you intend to install the project into Vue/vue-cli? Don't know if anything n there is affecting it

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the problem.